# Display data in Listview using Fragment in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I tried to display data in listview using fragment in Android, but it is not showing data. please check my code.
Adapter class:

```
public class AppAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<Apps1> {

    ArrayList<Apps1> actorList1;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public AppAdapter1(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Apps1> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList1 = objects;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvName.setText(actorList1.get(position).getPosition());
        return v;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
    }
}

public class FragmentThree1 extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Apps1> actorsList1;
    public ListView listView;
    String val="";
    AppAdapter1 adapter;
    public FragmentThree1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three_1, container, false);
        actorsList1 = new ArrayList<Apps1>();
new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://--------------");
 ListView listview = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list);
       // adapter = new AppAdapter1(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList1);
     adapter = new AppAdapter1(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList1);
         listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        return myFragmentView;
   } }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhsKr.png)

I retrieved data from JSON URL, but in displaying listview using it is not showing data. please check my above code.

Comment: actorsList1 size is 0

Comment: actorList1 size is 1

Comment: print this in log "actorList1.get(position).getPosition()" . check which value is return

Comment: actorsList1 size is 1, but printing "actorsList1.get(position).getPosition()" displays 'actorsList1 : size = 0'

Answer (score 0):

in this class `JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://--------------");` where you add the data in your ArrayList `actorsList1` after that just call this line.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Reason** is your `Async` class is fetching data while your adapter set the data so when your `Async` task completed you need to `notify` your adapter to change the `DataSet`

Try this it'll solve your problem.